# RxJS: Depending on previous values to recover an object and then join and emit those previous values with the recovered object

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-observables

I have a case in which I have a bunch of ids that I recover from `route.params`, like this:

```ts
const ids$ = this.route.params.pipe(
  map(params => {
    const modelId = +params['modelId'];
    const deliverId = +params['deliverId'];
    const compositionId = +params['compositionId'];

    return { modelId, deliverId, compositionId };
  })
);
```

After that, I have to recover the `composition` object from the server, so I do this:

```ts
const getComposition$ = ids$.pipe(
  switchMap(ids =>
    this.compositionsService.getComposition(ids.compositionId)
  )
);
```

And now I want to have an aggregated object with the two first ids and, instead of the last one (`compositionId`), the `composition` object, I mean this:

```ts
entities: {
  modelId: number;
  deliverId: number;
  composition: Composition;
};
```

So I do this:

```ts
const aggregated$ = forkJoin(ids$, getComposition$).pipe(
  map(arr => ({
    modelId: arr[0].modelId,
    deliverId: arr[0].deliverId,
    aggregated: arr[1]
  }))
);
```

And then, I subscribe to it:

```ts
const aggregated$.subscribe(aggregated => {
  console.log(aggregated);
});
```

But it never prints anything on the console. Interestingly enough, if I check if the call to the server is made, it actually is, but the last observable (`aggregated$`) never emits anything.

What am I doing wrong? Is it there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said both `ids$` and `getComposition$` are in fact `this.route.params` which comes from Angular. The `forkJoin` operator needs all its source Observables to emit at least one item and **all of them have to complete**. And this is what's not happening when you use `this.route.params` because it's a Subject that is never completed.

So you can use for example `take(1)` to complete both sources `ids$` and `getComposition$`:

```
forkJoin(ids$.pipe(take(1)), getComposition$.pipe(take(1))
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

From Observable documentation:

> forkJoin: Wait for Observables to complete and then combine last
>   values they emitted.

I thinks that `forkJoin` in your case does not emit since `ids$` does not complete.

What you can try is something along these lines

```
const getComposition$ = ids$.pipe(
  switchMap(ids =>
    this.compositionsService.getComposition(ids.compositionId).pipe(
       map(composition => ({composition, modelId: ids.modelId, deliverId: ids.deliverId))
    )
  )
);
```